# Coefficient of thermal expansion

Tags: pressure, temperature, thermal-conductivity, volume

Is the coefficient of thermal expansion of a particular material under constant pressure constant?

Answer (score 1):

In short, a linear coefficient of thermal expansion is an approximation.

In most cases, our daily lives occur in relatively small temperature deviations around about 290°K, and are very far from absolute zero temperature (0°K), so even complicated thermal dependencies are often reasonably well approximated by linear expressions.  Thermal expansion is one of those, but, in general, thermal expansion is not linear, but can be fairly complex, as it's related to the material specific non-linear molecular dynamics.

It is difficult to find information on this since searching for eg, "temperature dependence thermal expansion" usually just turns up linear thermal expansion.  For tables of temperature dependent coefficients, one thing to look for is "secant coefficient thermal expansion" (or CTE).  The idea here is that "tangent" thermal expansion is a linearization around a point on the curve, but secant CTE is a linearization that spans the end points of the temperature range of interest to account for CTE changing with temperature.